# C++ unordered_set insert insert PHP

Tags: php, c++, unordered-set

I have a code on C++ which I have to rewrite on PHP. 
Weird thing happens for me as I'm PHP programmer and don't know C++ well.
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

int func(int choice) {

    unordered_set<int> hset;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < choice; counter++) {
        hset.insert(counter);
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            hset.insert(counter);
            hset.insert(counter + 1);
        }
    }
    return hset.size();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << func(561);
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the code is: `562`;

I have written PHP code like this:

```
function func($choice) {

$hset = [];

for ($counter = 0; $counter < $choice; $counter++) {
    array_push($hset, $counter);
    if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
        array_push($hset, $counter);
        array_push($hset, $counter + 1);
    }
}

    return count($hset);
}

echo func(561);
```

It returns `1123`. Please help.

Comment: Why are you using `unordered_set`? Do you know what its purpose is? The reason I ask is because you are inserting a bunch of duplicate elements into the set, and `unordered_set` only keeps 1 copy of each unique element.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That is the problem: the OP (admittedly) doesn't know C++ well. You have a point though: that particular part of the original code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MrLister: Yeah, I'm just curious what made him think `unordered_set` was the right container the job here (whatever that job is).It's not generally one of the first containers you learn about when learning C++, and one of the first containers most people do learn about (`std::vector`) is, afaict, the right container for the job.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm rewriting already written c++ code which is for tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++'s [`unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) will not allow duplicate elements. Since you are pushing `counter` and `counter+1` in, you are generally trying to push the same element twice, and one of those times it gets rejected.

If you want to have similar behavior as PHP, use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, with [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) (or [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)) to add your elements.

If you want to go the other way, then in PHP you could use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)